# Showing $E(X + a) = E(X) + a$ for Non-Negative Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have been working through the lecture notes given [here](http://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Ettkocz/teaching/1819/prob-notes.pdf). Specifically I have been looking at page 4

> Theorem 1.2. part a) and part b)
>
> Let $X$ and $Y$ be a non-negative random variable.
>
> a) $X$ $\leq$ $Y$, then $E(X)$ $\leq$ $E(Y)$
>
> b) Then for $a\geq 0$ $E(X+a) = E(X) +a$.

The proof given in the text says given $E(Z + a) = E(Z) + a$ for simple random variables $Z$.
We need to simply follow the proof of part a). However, I cannot make the jump from the proof in part a) to the proof in part b). The proof in part a) is as follows:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $X \geq 0$, there exists a simple random variable $Z$ s.t $Z \leq X$ and $E(Z) \geq E(X) - \epsilon$. Since $X \leq Y$, we have that $Z \leq Y$. Hence, $E(X) - \epsilon \leq E(Z) \leq E(Y)$. Taking $\epsilon$ to zero gives us the desired result.

Thank you.

Comment: If you use the definition of the expectation of a nonnegative random variable $X$ given in the notes ($E[X] = \sup \{E[Z] : \text{$Z$ simple and $Z \le X$}\}$) I think you can prove (b) directly using the observation that $E[Z+a]=E[Z] + a$ for simple $Z$.

Comment: Oh I am silly! Yea I think you are correct. I do not know why the author refers to the proof of part a then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notes do not say "Then".  As you say, the proof given of (b) starts with $E(a+Z) =a+EZ$ for simple $Z$ and then suggests repeating the steps for $X$ in the proof of part (a)

So possibly: given $\epsilon_1 > 0$ and since $X \geq 0$ and $X+a\ge 0$, there exists a simple random variable $Z_1$ such that  $Z_1 \leq X$ and $E(Z_1) \geq E(X) - \epsilon$ and a simple random variable equal to $(Z_2+a)$ satisfing $(Z_2+a) \leq (X+a)$ and $E(Z_2+a) \ge E(X+a) - \epsilon$.  Putting these together gives

and $$E(X+a) \geq E(Z_1+a)=E(Z_1)+a \geq E(X)+a - \epsilon$$ and
$$E(X)+a \geq E(Z_2)+a=E(Z_2+a) \geq E(X+a) - \epsilon$$

Sending $\epsilon$  towards zero gives $E(X)+a = E(X+a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Statement b) is true in general, not only for non-negative rv

$$\mathbb{E}[X+a]=\int(x+a)dF=\int xdF+a\int dF=\mathbb{E}[X]+a$$

Same proof for $\mathbb{E}[aX]=a\mathbb{E}[X]$

Comment: I understand this proof but I wanted to prove it using properties of simple random variables.